# Wireshark anlayse packet data TCP/IP

Tags: networking, tcp, wireshark

I'm using wireshark for the first time.

I run a client program that sends a command to server but the server response length is zero. I need to anlayse packets sent back from the server using wire shark in order to understand the problem

> How can I see what is the size of data sent in a packet & what is the
>   data (human readable string) sent to destination using wireshark.

[image]

[image]

Please guide I'm new to networking and wireshark.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution .Since, I'm using TCP .

1. Click the packet you want to analyse
2. See description- goto tcp
3. Under TCP click on data to see size of data and its value

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this page for a guide on wireshark: [Wireshark guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/)